# R regex semicolon

Tags: regex, r, grepl

I want to check if all elements of a list have the pattern I need them to have, otherwise I will stop the whole script.

The example list looks like this:

```
[1]
Archaea;Euryarchaeota;Methanobacteria;Methanobacteriales;Methanobacteriaceae;Methanobrevibacter;
[2]
Archaea;Euryarchaeota;Methanobacteria;Methanobacteriales;Methanobacteriaceae;Methanosphaera;
[3]
Archaea;Euryarchaeota;Methanobacteria;Methanobacteriales;Methanobacteriaceae;Methanosphaera;
[4]
Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Bifidobacteriales;Bifidobacteriaceae;Bifidobacterium;
[5]
Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Bifidobacteriales;Bifidobacteriaceae;Bifidobacterium;
[6]
Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Bifidobacteriales;Bifidobacteriaceae;Bifidobacterium;
[7]
Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Coriobacteriales;Coriobacteriaceae;Gordonibacter;
[8]
Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Coriobacteriia;Coriobacteriales;Coriobacteriaceae;;
[9]
Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Coriobacteriia;Coriobacteriales;Coriobacteriaceae;;
```

Want I all entries to have exactly six semicolons.
I tried to do a pattern matching with grepl but I have troubles with the right pattern. 
Here is what I tried

```
if(!any(grepl(";{6}", taxonomy))) { Through error message if the
taxonomy is not in the right format   stop("Wrong number of taxonomic
classes\n Taxonomic levels have to be separated by semicolons (six in
total).  IMPORTANT: if taxonomic information at any level is missing,
the semicolons are still needed:\n  
e.g.Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Prevotellaceae;Prevotella;
      e.g.Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Prevotellaceae;;")
} else {
```

But I always get FALSE.

Comment: look at `str_count` from `stringr` package

Answer (score 2):

`count.fields` returns the number of fields in each line of the file or connection given as its first argument using the `sep` argument as the field separator.  No packages are used.

```
f <- function(x) {
  ok <- count.fields(textConnection(x), sep = ";") == 7
  if (any(!ok)) stop("these row numbers do not have 7 fields: ", which(!ok))
  # add whatever other code you need
}
```

Testing it out:

```
# x has 2 components having 7 and 3 semicolon-separated fields respectively
x <- c("Archaea;Euryarchaeota;Methanobacteria;Methanobacteriales;Methanobacteriaceae;Methanobrevibacter;", ";;")
f(x)
## Error in f(x) : these row numbers do not have 7 fields: 2
```

See `?count.fields` and `?textConnection` .

Answer (score 1):

```
;{6}
```

matches `";;;;;;"` and nothing else. You want to check for something like

```
(?:[^;]*;){6}
```

which matches if (at least) 6 semicolons are present in the string.

If you need to assert that each line you test has *exactly* 6 semicolons, you need to be more specific:

```
^(?:[^;]*;){6}[^;]*$
```

where `^`  and `$` are start/end of string [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and `[^;]*` is a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches any number of characters except semicolons.

*R Code*

```
> x<-c('Archaea;Euryarchaeota;Methanobacteria;Methanobacteriales;Methanobacteriaceae;Methanobrevibacter;',
  'Archaea;Euryarchaeota;Methanobacteria;Methanobacteriales;Methanobacteriaceae;Methanosphaera;',
  'Archaea;Euryarchaeota;Methanobacteria;Methanobacteriales;Methanobacteriaceae;Methanosphaera;',
  'Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Bifidobacteriales;Bifidobacteriaceae;Bifidobacterium;',
  'Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Bifidobacteriales;Bifidobacteriaceae;Bifidobacterium;',
  'Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Bifidobacteriales;Bifidobacteriaceae;Bifidobacterium;',
  'Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Coriobacteriales;Coriobacteriaceae;Gordonibacter;',
  'Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Coriobacteriia;Coriobacteriales;Coriobacteriaceae;;',
  'Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Coriobacteriia;Coriobacteriales;Coriobacteriaceae;;')
> grepl("^(?:[^;]*;){6}[^;]*$", x)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[9] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr` you can do something like,

```
library(stringr)
which(str_count(taxonomy, ';') == 6)
```

or

```
grepl(6, str_count(taxonomy, ';'))
```